# Get another document with Id from matched document's field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 5.1, let's say after my query matched some documents, i wan't it to be able to attach another supplement document given the the Id is same as a field in the former document. Thanks.

Edit: include an example.

document 1 { lang:en, contents:'abc', shared_field:'xxx' }

document 2 { lang:fr, contents:'ghi', shared_id:'1' }

problem: my query is for lang 'fr', but i need to fetch and attached shared field from 'en' version of the doc as well.

Apology for bad english.

Comment: You should illustrate your question with an example, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Please see my edit for an example

Comment: Ok, why don't you also index the `shared_field` in your document 2?